# Create CSS class name dynamically?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to do something like this:

**View**

```
<td class="status_@Model.IsActive">
      @Model.Description
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .status_True
    {
        background-color: Red;
    }
    .status_False
    {
        background-color: Green;
    }
</style>
```

`@Model.IsActive` is return `True` or `False`. Of course this code is not working.

Html output of class is : `class="status_@Model.IsActive"`

My expected output is : `class="status_True"`

Is this possible to do something like this logic? If is possible, How can I do? Or another way to change css class? There may be different ways.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this with CSS, maybe [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) will help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Razor syntax takes some getting used to. Use parenthesis to get the actual property value:

```
<td class="status_@(Model.IsActive)">
```

Here's a [quick reference from Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)